# Adding Label In Fetched Data Of While Loop Of scanner.next()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i'm having a problem on how i add label in while loop of `scanner.next()`
**here's my code:**

```
public void readCSV() throws FileNotFoundException{
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Sample/employees.csv"))) {
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            int c = 1;
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String a ="";
                if(c == 1){
                    a = "ID:";
                }
                if (c ==2){
                    a = "Name:";
                }
                if (c ==3){
                    a = "Age:";
                }
                if (c ==4){
                    a = "Position:";
                }
                if (c ==5){
                    a = "Salary:";
                }    
                if (c ==6){
                    c = 1;
                }  

                System.out.print(a+scanner.next()+"\n");  
                c++;

            }
        }
       }
```

**Result of this function:**

```
Employee Record System!
Choose an Operation
(1) View Employee
(2) Add Employee
(3) View Employee by Id
(4) Generate Employee Record
(5) Exit
1
ID:2095
Name:Juan Dela Cruz
Age:24
Position:Programmer
Salary:50000.00
6727
Bruce 
25
Programmer
35000.00
3750
John
23
Junior Programmer
35000.00
8435
Alvin
41
Senior Programmer
100000.00
```

i want is in every 5 data of fetched data having their specific label:

**Expected output:**

```
ID:2095
Name:Juan Dela Cruz
Age:24
Position:Programmer
Salary:50000.00
ID:6727
Name:Bruce 
Age:25
Position:Programmer
Salary:35000.00
ID:3750
Name:John
Age:23
Position:Junior Programmer
Salary:35000.00
ID:8435
Name:Alvin
Age:41
Position:Senior Programmer
Salary:100000.00
```

Comment: Try setting the delimiter to both `,` and `\n`: `scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change while loop to this

```
 while(scanner.hasNext()){
              String a ="";
              if(c == 1){
                  a = "ID:";
              }
              if (c ==2){
                  a = "Name:";
              }
              if (c ==3){
                  a = "Age:";
              }
              if (c ==4){
                  a = "Position:";
              }
              if (c ==5){
                  a = "Salary:";
                  c = 0;
              }
```

When you set c=1 in a separate if clause, it has already read the id value and it will be printed without a label. It will also display other labels in an incorrect order. Also as Johnny also pointed out you may need to add new line character to delimiters as well.

Comment: Because of the `c++` later, you want to set `c = 0;`.

Comment: let me try this